# Unable to get response from API using ASP.Net .ashx helper file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is the code for my helper page. The API I am trying to connect to is MASV.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports RestSharp

Public Class NewToken Implements IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState

Private _Delegate As AsyncProcessorDelegate
Protected Delegate Sub AsyncProcessorDelegate(context As HttpContext)

Public Function BeginProcessRequest(context As HttpContext, cb As AsyncCallback, extraData As Object) As IAsyncResult Implements IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest
    _Delegate = New AsyncProcessorDelegate(AddressOf ProcessRequest)
    Return _Delegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData)
End Function

Async Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpAsyncHandler.ProcessRequest
    Try
        Dim converted As String = Await new_token()
        context.Response.Write(converted)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim whatIsIt As String = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub EndProcessRequest(result As IAsyncResult) Implements IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest
    _Delegate.EndInvoke(result)
End Sub

Public Async Function new_token() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Try
        Dim client As New RestClient("https://api.massive.app/v1")
        Dim request As New RestRequest("teams/ID/packages", Method.Post)
        request.AddHeader("X-Api-Key", "API KEY")
        Dim pkgRequest As New PackageRequest With {
            .description = "MASV",
            .name = "File Upload",
            .recipient = "test@test.com"
        }
        request.AddJsonBody(pkgRequest)
        Dim result As RestResponse(Of UploadPackage) = Await client.ExecuteAsync(Of UploadPackage)(request)
        Dim converted As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data)
        Return converted
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim whatIsIt As String = ex.Message
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Teams ID and API Key hidden for confidentiality. PackageRequest & UploadPackage are custom classes. I get back "An error occurred while sending the request." I have put await and async keywords everywhere I need to. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Not really too easy to know, but would suggest the easiest thing to start with would be to get the request working via some tool like Postman first, then you can inspect that request and use it as a template for your application calls

Comment: I was using another program that had this request working, but it was in a newer framework (ASP.Net MVC vs. ASP.Net Classic here)

Comment: @matt The error message indicates that there was a problem with the request itself. Did you try checking the exception's `InnerException` value?

I created a small program in VB.net core (v6) by copying the relevant parts from your `new_token()` function, with a few modifications. The request did eventually go through and I was getting 401 responses (which is expected). Unfortuntately, without full context, I can't tell where the exact issue is in your implementation as there are some pieces missing.

(P.S. I work at MASV)

Comment: Beyond the ID and API Key what else is missing?

Comment: @Majed I have also tried: `Dim result1 As UploadPackage = Await client.PostAsync(Of UploadPackage)(request)`  And that throws an exception that says the connection was closed by the remote server